# How to check transaction situation via CLI

Tags: solidity, transactions, mining, confirmations, cli

I did a transaction and got transaction hash. How can I check this transaction is mined (or confirmed) via CLI (command-line interface) ? What is related command for this? Here is transaction hash that i received: 0x0e16981f972c8069398a7aa6c6402b8183063cfd157c3714582101e3ee071a30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by CLI you mean shell script, one way is

```
echo 'eth.getTransactionReceipt("<txn hash>")' | geth attach <your web3 provider>
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried to install CLI shell script on windows, however, i could not find its installer. Also, would you please tell me the correct value for <my web3 provider> its UI version is here https://tobalaba.etherscan.com/tx/0x0e16981f972c8069398a7aa6c6402b8183063cfd157c3714582101e3ee071a30 Thanks